# How to enable 'for...in' my NativeJavaObject within Rhino?

Tags: javascript, .net, rhino, ikvm

I am newbie in rhino.

Currently, I am using Rhino 1.7R framework thru .NET 4 and IKVM.NET. 
I  exposed several wrapped classes implementing NativeJavaObject using setWrapFractory() API.

```
public class InterceptNativeObject : NativeJavaObject
{
    public InterceptNativeObject()
    {

    }

    public override Object get(String name, Scriptable start)
    {
        Object res = base.get(name, start);
        if (res is NativeJavaMethod)
        {
            NativeJavaMethod method = (NativeJavaMethod)res;
            return new RhinoMethodWrapFunction(method);
        }
        if (res == org.mozilla.javascript.UniqueTag.NOT_FOUND &&
            base.javaObject is IPropertBox && base.javaObject != null)
        {
            object ret = ((IPropertBox)base.javaObject)._x__GetPropertyValue(name);

            return Utils.ConvertCLRValueToJavaValue(ret);
        }
        return res;
     }

     .....
}
```

Now, I can access all .NET methods and properties as I wanted.

My current problem is to support 'for...in' my NativeJavaObject classes.
When I evaluate

```
     'for(var prop in myClass){printf(prop);};' ,
```

it returns 'no 'in' call for non-object' error.

It seems the 'get' attempting to searching an object of ' **_*iterator*_**', but it resulted in 'not found' at get() function. So, it ends up with exception.
  So far, I tried

- added java.util.iterator
- return this.getIds().GetEnumrator();

None of works.

How can i allow property enumrate access for my Wrapped NativeJavaObject?
   What is Rhino's expected return value of ' **_*iterator*_**' to enable 'for...in'?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`__iterator__` is part of a [Mozilla specific language extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).  That link explains that the `__iterator__` method returns an object with a `next` method that throws `StopIteration` when the iterator is exhausted.

You have to [opt in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/New_in_Rhino_1.7R1) to iterators and generators though:

> To enable JavaScript 1.7 support, you must set the version as 170 using the `Context.setLanguageVersion()` API call. If you are using the Rhino shell, you can specify `-version 170` on the command line or call version(170) in code executed by the shell.

You can write JS in rhino that will wrap a Java iterator to present it as a JS iterator:

```
function javaIteratorToJsIterator(javaIterator) {
  return {
    next: function () {
      if (!javaIterator.hasNext()) { throw StopIteration; }
      return javaIterator.next();
    }
  };
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use Mozilla style generators but I think you need to create the Rhino interpreter with an option to enable them.

> While custom iterators are a useful tool, their creation requires careful programming due to the need to explicitly maintain their internal state. Generators provide a powerful alternative: they allow you to define an iterative algorithm by writing a single function which can maintain its own state.
>
> A generator is a special type of function that works as a factory for iterators. A function becomes a generator if it contains one or more yield expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much. "__iterator___" was looking for a Function to process, not object self. I will try also with setLanguageVersion(170).  Thanks again for providing very useful information!

Comment: I finally did iterate the NativeJavaObject by creating Iterator class as 'ScriptableObject'. Now it runs 'for(var a in document){}' and 'if('location' in window){}'. Thank you again!